# dual drives each with ubuntu - GRUB lists both but only opens one?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, multiple-instances

I have two drives (HDD and SSD), with ubuntu 20.04 installed on each drive. GRUB lists both instances separately (sdb/2 - HDD; sda/7 - SSD). But no matter which I select in GRUB, the instance on HDD opens.

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks so much!

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? What brand/model hardware? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: thanks for your response and for providing the link! I'm using UEFI with Dell Inspiron 660; HDD is the original WD 1TB; I also installed a Samsung SSD 500GB. I will follow your instructions. Thanks so much!